# In SBT 1.3.8 how can I figure out who is bringing in a dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt

When I start an app using sbt jetty:quickstart I get a container initialisation error. I think this is because my app is bringing in an old servlet instance. I dont explicitly mention this dependency.

I've found file:/C:/Users/drewb/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar on my classpath for jetty:quickstart and I guess this is causing the error. I am trying to figure out how I can identify who is bringing in this dependency so I can get rid of it.

In SBT 1.3.8 how can I figure out who is bringing in a dependency? Because sbt-dependency-graph doesnt work with 1.3.x Im looking for an alternative - hopefully the sbt team had something in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make this work with sbt 1.3.8. I dropped back to 1.2.8 and wound up using coursierDependencyTree with the coursier plugin. addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "2.0.0-RC6-1") https://get-coursier.io/docs/sbt-coursier

Comment: It works in 1.3.9 (presumably also in 1.3.8) with an older version of the sbt-coursier plugin.  addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.3").  Thanks to domainexpert's comment at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5040 for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sbt-dependency-graph for dependency hierarchy look up

https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Comment: sbt >= 1.3.x is currently not supported (but hopefully fixed soon), Unfortunately, this problem cannot be fixed in sbt-dependency-graph itself but is a regression in sbt. If you'd like to continue using sbt-dependency-graph, please add your support to sbt/sbt#4706 and sbt/sbt#4707.